# async/await Promise.all() but get response as the promises resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

Run all promises in parallel using Promise.all() but get response of each promise as it resolves and do processing on that.

Is there a work around like I can attach a callback to `promises.resolve` that as a certain promise resolves it calls a callback

Example

```
let p1 = Promise.resolve(1)
let p2 = Promise.resolve(2)
let p3 = Promise.resolve(3)

Promise.all([p1,p2,p3])

function processData(data)
{
.... 
}
```

I want to run all of them in parallel but don't want to wait till all of them get resolved but instead call `processData()` as soon as a promise resolves for each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the promises with `forEach` instead, attaching `processData` to each in a `.then`:

```js
const processData = console.log;

let p1 = Promise.resolve(1);
let p2 = Promise.resolve(2);
let p3 = Promise.resolve(3);
[p1, p2, p3].forEach(prom => prom
  .then(processData)
  .catch((err) => {
    /* handle errors */
  })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a `.then` after resolving and assign processData as a callback.

```
let p1 = Promise.resolve(1).then(processData);
let p2 = Promise.resolve(1).then(processData);
let p3 = Promise.resolve(1).then(processData);

Promise.all([p1,p2,p3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `Promise.all()`:

```
let p1 = Promise.resolve(1).then(processData);
let p2 = Promise.resolve(2).then(processData);
let p3 = Promise.resolve(3).then(processData);
```

If you need to call `processData` as soon as a promise resolves but want to wait for all promises to resolve before continuing then use `Promise.all()` only for the wait but call `processData` inside each promise's `.then()`:

```
(async () {
  let p1 = Promise.resolve(1).then(processData);
  let p2 = Promise.resolve(2).then(processData);
  let p3 = Promise.resolve(3).then(processData);

  await Promise.all([p1,p2,p3]);

  // continue processing..

})();
```